# Web Api can't handle this request in production

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

I have noticed that over the last year while my app has been in production, it sometimes just switches off.

When I debug the web api project locally and use the connection string of the database on Azure, it works.
Whenever I then publish the project to Azure, it says Error 500, can't handle this request. Even with the connection string hard coded in the appsettings.json.

What I did notice though was when I changed firewall settings on the database server recently, that's when it switched off. I don't know if that's the source.

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 0):

And would you think it, it was the server IP address.
I had to find the virtual IP address of the web app under Properties in the left pane and add it to the server rules of the database.